# How to accept user input in GUI? - Java

Tags: java, swing

My program takes an input amount of money and converts it into coins. I need it to have a GUI, and have to make it possible to enter the amount while in the GUI, and then do various things with JButtons and such. I have the program written but I can't figure out how to accept user input in GUI, and be able to use that input in my methods? I guess I'm looking for a scanner class that can be used in GUI?

Comment: No, don't use a Scanner class, you're thinking linear, like one would for a console program, but that's not what you're now making. Think **event driven** and read the Swing tutorials.

Comment: There isn't really anything directly like that, instead I think a good place to start is [The Java Tutorials: Getting Started With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html).

Comment: I'll read up on those guys, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have JTextField placed in your gui. Input should be done on the textboxes. You also need Jbutton. Buttons are needed for interaction between the user and your program. You can have button like "calculate".

So how does the program knows what to do with the buttons? You also need actionListener for the buttons. So you code your logic/actions to be performed in your actionListener.

The actionListener listens for actions (E.g.button press) so that respective actions can be performed.

How user interacts with the program with a GUI is very different from a console program. You no longer use scanner to scan for user input.

In **console** program you do this:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scn.nextLine();
```

In **GUI** you do this instead:

```
JTextField txtInput = new JTextField("");

public class txtInputListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        input = txtInput.getText();   //receive input from text field
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

This is not the full code, but it gives you the idea.

Comment: Perhaps a ramification of this broad question and this correct but equally general answer is how do you block control of the flow of execution while doing a calculation to yield it to the GUI and then continue the flow with the result of the interaction?